# Angular 14 routing showing a blank page

Tags: angular

I've just finished updating an Angular 7 app to Angular 14 and finally got to the point when where it is compiling with errors.
However, when I load the app in the browser I get a blank page at the /login route.

Amongst the rest of the routes in the app-routing,module file I have:

```
 { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginPageModule) }
```

Which correctly points to the correct module. The app directs to this page after checking for a current user session, of which there isn't one. But nothing happens, the LoginPage does not load, console.logs in the constructor or onInit method don't appear in the console.

The LoginPage is not standalone and has the follwing structure:
-- login
-- login.module.ts
-- login.page.html
-- login.page.scss
-- login.page.ts

If I switch the routing to aim at the component like so:

```
 { path: 'login', component: LoginPage },
```

then the console elements tab shows the html as being correct yet nothing shows in the browser.

The LoginModule contains the following:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatDialogModule, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { LoginPage } from './login.page';
import { ComponentsModule } from 'src/app/components/components.module';

const routes: Routes = [
 {
    path: '',
    component: LoginPage
 }
];

@NgModule({
   imports: [
     CommonModule,
     ComponentsModule,
     FormsModule,
     IonicModule,
     MatAutocompleteModule,
     MatDialogModule,
     MatInputModule,
     ReactiveFormsModule,
     RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
    { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginPage
  ]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

I'm a bit lost here so any help would be appreciated. Happy to share more code if it will help.

UPDATE:
The LoginPage imports a ComonentsModule that has a lot of components used in various places in the app, like headers and footers. I removed the components import and now I can see the LoginPge loading some data in the console but still nothing on the page.

I'll work on a stackblizt to replicate it the situation if I can.

Comment: I am pretty sure that your problem is not contained in the code you provided. I tried to reproduce this issue in Stackblitz, but it was working fine. Can you try to reproduce this issue in a stackblitz example?

Comment: My best bet - error in the console .)

Comment: Why are you providing MAT_DIALOG_DATA and MatDialogRef in module? Normally MatDialog service manages these tokens. Is your non-showing component using dialog?
If this is a problem, then title is misleading because it's no router case.

Comment: do you import `import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`? in your main.module?

Comment: @Eliseo, yes, BrowserAnimationModule is there

Comment: @EdmundsFolkmanis, The login page makes use of a dialog but I'll take that out and see if it was having an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Working Example created in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbefjt?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).